# Maven. Creating a project offline fails so how do I begin?

Tags: maven

First off I'm not on a separate system in order to post this question and have no way of connecting the other system to the internet. This machine I'm on is locked down so I am not able to install or do anything other than email and view the web for research.

Used Reference: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Environment: Maven 2.2.1
Yes the Maven build functions fine for the existing project.

Situation:
    I'm new to Maven and this project I'm on, the other developers are GONE. There is a .bat file that was used to run the project builds and that's all I know of Maven.

I am attempting to learn Maven on the other machine that has it installed I am using the Apache site mentioned above. The instructions tells me to create a project using the command
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false` but, I get the
**'BUILD FAILURE'** 
Error reading archetype catalog http://repo1.maven.org/maven2... (and other errors)
The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype=quickstart:1.0

So, question is what am I to do in order to create a dummy project so I can see WTF is going on with Maven when I'm in an environment that is not able to reach the 'maven.org' site?

If there are threads on learning Maven offline that someone can point me to that too would be of use. I'm not seeing anything though that helps me get started on this.

Thank you for looking and your time.

Comment: If you have a JDK on the locked PC, you might try to "install maven" (which means: unzip maven to any folder, add JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME to your environment, and PATH).

Comment: You're not likely to find working documents/examples for maven 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems that maven is looking  for the architype on the central repository.

You can create your own pom.xml with an editor:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html